# Footer in Sliding Up Panel hiding content

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) widget along with footer property to show a few bottoms at the bottom. The issue is that the content of panel gets hidden behind the footer content. I tried adding padding as suggested in the document, but that doesn't seem to give the desired results.

Following is an abstract from the widget documentation.

> Footer: Optional persistent widget that floats above the panel and attaches to
> the bottom of the panel. Content at the bottom of the panel will be
> covered by this widget. Add padding to the bottom of the panel to
> avoid coverage.

```
SlidingUpPanel(
  backdropEnabled: true,
  color: Colors.transparent,
  minHeight: 140,
  maxHeight: 300,
  parallaxEnabled: true,
  footer: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("Subscribe"),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text("Chat"),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Learn More"),
              ))
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  panel: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 90.0),
    child: Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
          topRight: Radius.circular(30),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 3,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment:
                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Main Heading"),
                  Text("Sub Heading"),
                  Text(
                      "Text area 1 Text area 1 Text area 1 Text area 1 Text area 1 Text area 1 Text area 1 Text area 1 Text area 1 Text area 1 Text area 1 Text area 1 Text area 1"),
                  Text("Text area 2"),
                  Text("Text area 3"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

The output is demonstrated in the images below:

**Panel Closed**
[image]

You can notice the text is hidden behind the buttons.

**Panel Open**

[image]

I tried adding bottom padding to the panel. And that added the grey area at the bottom of the panel when it is open.

Please help prevent getting this text being hidden behind the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bottom padding can only help to make the contents visible when the  **panel is open**. When it is closed you would need a top padding - which you can add, but the padding in this case will be there when you open the panel as well.

So what you can try is to maintain the opened / closed state of the panel and adjust the content according to this state.

Create a member variable in the state class:

```
double _panelPosition = 0;
```

Add callback functions to the `SlidingUpPanel` to track the state:

```
SlidingUpPanel(
   onPanelSlide: (position) => setState(() => _panelPosition = position),
  ...
)
```

Now you can for example show / hide the contents depending on the panel position, wrap the `Column` which contains "Main Heading, Sub Heading" etc. into a `Visibility` widget:

```
child: Visibility(
  visible: _panelPosition > 0,
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [<your text widgets>],
  ),
),
```

Or you can use an `AnimatedOpacity` instead to make it smoother:

```
child: AnimatedOpacity(
  opacity: _panelPosition,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [<your text widgets>],
  ),
),
```

Or with a dynamically changing top padding, which reaches 0 if the panel is open (use `Expanded` and `SingleChildScrollView` to avoid overflow):

```
Expanded(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 100 - _panelPosition * 100),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [<your text widgets>],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

You can fine tune the aboce versions to control when to start showing the contents etc.

NOTE: The above code will result in multiple rebuilds during you open the panel. If you want to avoid it you can use a `bool` variable instead of `double` and track only fully closed (`position == 0`) and fully open (`position == 1`) states. Of course you can't use `AnimatedOpacity` in this case.